# \baselineskip not working on array

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing, arrays

I want to add a linebreak with distance proportional to `\baselineskip` in `array` environment, in order to make my document more stable to format change.

However, it seems as `\baselineskip` is zero in this environment.

Why is it so? Any solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\(
    \begin{array}{l}
        1 + 1  = 2 \\
        e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0\\[1.2\baselineskip]
        \text{Another equation}  \\
        1 + 0 = 1
    \end{array}
\)
  
One sentence.\\[\baselineskip]
Another sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `\baselineskip` is set to zero inside `array` and `tabular`, because these environments space lines using struts.

You can use `\normalbaselineskip` instead, that saves the value of `\baselineskip`.

When a font size changing command is executed, first LaTeX stores the appropriate value in `\normalbaselineskip` and then does `\baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip`.

Comment: Your solution is simpler (I guess equivalent to mine), so accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the very last cause of this problem, but I found a workaround. I save the value of `\baselineskip` in a self defined length `\myskip` outside the `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\myskip}
\setlength{\myskip}{\baselineskip}
\(
    \begin{array}{l}
        1 + 1  = 2 \\
        e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0\\[1.2\myskip]
        \text{Another equation}  \\
        1 + 0 = 1
    \end{array}
\)
  
One sentence.\\[\baselineskip]
Another sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image]